# Open my url page in the same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, href

is there a html code or some magic do it ?
if i sent my url page to some one in facebook Message,i want my url page to open in same tab directly not on a new tab .

Answer (score 2):

i think it's not possible because face book not let you do this .

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the **target** attribute on Facebook, there for... it is not possible.

Just need to add that on Facebook api there is target attribute under [Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button), and they let you choose target, default is _blank.

Answer (score 1):

try this. `<br/>window.open("www.youraddress.com","_self")`